# Firebase phone number authentication with Vue.js does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am building a new Vue.js app based on the [Webpack template](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/). I have a /sign-in route that loads a component called SignIn. I am trying to use [Firebase Phone Number authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) using the Firebase SDK to authenticate my users.

I've installed Firebase with `npm install firebase` and initialized it in my main.js file like this:

**/src/main.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

// Initialize Firebase
const config = {
  apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'MY_PROJECT.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://MY_PROJECT.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'MY_PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'MY_PROJECT.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'MY_SENDER_ID',
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
});
```

My credentials are redacted for security in the above example.

When the user is on /sign-in, this is the component that they see:

**/src/components/pages/SignIn.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Number Input Form -->
    <div v-if="showNumberInput">
      <form v-on:submit.prevent>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="numberInputForm.number" placeholder="Phone number" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="get-sign-in-code" class="btn btn-block btn-lg success theme-accent">{{ getSignInCodeButton.text }}</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- SMS Verification Form -->
    <div v-if="showCodeInput">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="9944" placeholder="Verification Code" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <a href="javascript:void" class="btn btn-block btn-lg success theme-accent" @click="signIn">{{ signInButton.text }}</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
  name: 'SignIn',

  data() {
    return {
      // UI States
      showNumberInput: true,
      showCodeInput: false,

      // Forms
      numberInputForm: {
        number: '',
      },

      // Buttons
      getSignInCodeButton: {
        text: 'Get sign in code',
      },
      signInButton: {
        text: 'Sign in',
      },
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    const self = this;

    // Start Firebase invisible reCAPTCHA verifier
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('get-sign-in-code', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {
        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
        self.sendSMS();
      }
    });
  },

  methods: {
    /**
     * Sends the user an SMS-verification code using Firebase auth
     *
     * @see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth
     */
    sendSMS() {
      const self = this;

      self.getSignInCodeButton = {
        showSpinner: true,
        text: 'Sending SMS..',
        disabled: true,
      };
    },


    /**
     * Authenticates the user with Firebase auth
     */
    signIn() {
      // Redirect the user to the authenticated page
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see, I have two forms in the template - one to capture the phone number and another to allow the user to enter the verification code. I am toggling the visibility of these forms programmatically.

When the component mounts, I am calling the Firebase reCAPTCHA verifier and passing the ID of the submit button ("get-sign-in-code" in this case). However, when I click the button, nothing happens. I don't see the reCAPTCHA XHR in my dev tools network tab.

Could this be because the button is being inserted into the DOM dynamically and `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier()` cannot detect it when I pass the ID when the component mounts? How do I resolve this? Could I use $el or some other Vue.js method to get the reCAPTCHA verifier to work? Thanks.

## UPDATE

I was able to get this script to work by adding the following lines to the `mounted()` event:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then((widgetId) => {
  window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
});
```

This is how my `mounted()` method looks like now:

```
mounted() {
  const self = this;

  // Start Firebase invisible reCAPTCHA verifier
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('get-sign-in-code', {
    size: 'invisible',
    callback: () => {
      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
      self.sendSMS();
    },
  });

  window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then((widgetId) => {
    window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
  });
},
```

This however cause a new issue - the script now adds a randomly positioned "Protected by reCAPTCHA" badge that I'd like to get rid off. Is there any way to get this script to work without showing the badge?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is late to answer. But I see in your code when `mounted()` hook appeared you call `sendSMS()` function in `recaptchaVerifier` after callback. But when on subbitting first button which is:

```
<button type="submit" id="get-sign-in-code" class="btn btn-block btn-lg success theme-accent">{{ getSignInCodeButton.text }}</button>
```

no function showed to call on submit or on click. I guess you would update your button to react clicking on it like below: change is in **form tag** that showing which function to call on submit form.

```
<div v-if="showNumberInput">
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="sendSMS">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="numberInputForm.number" placeholder="Phone number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="get-sign-in-code" class="btn btn-block btn-lg success theme-accent">test</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone using nuxt.js (vuejs framework) then follow these steps

Inside your nuxt.config.js add the follwoing lines

```js
import 'firebase/compat/auth'; //import this on the top and

 modules: [
    ...// other code
    [
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',
      {
        config: {
          apiKey: '<apiKey>',
          authDomain: '<authDomain>',
          projectId: '<projectId>',
          storageBucket: '<storageBucket>',
          messagingSenderId: '<messagingSenderId>',
          appId: '<appId>',
          measurementId: '<measurementId>'
        },
        services: {
          auth: true // Just as example. Can be any other service.
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
```

then inside your file wherever you want to use phone authentication first import firebase like this

```js
<template>
///
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

methods : {
    // configure recaptcha
    
    configureRecaptcha() {
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
        "otp-verfiy-button",
        {
          size: "invisible",
          callback: (response) => {
            sendOtpForVerification();
          },
        }
      );
    },
    
    // handle otpsend
      sendOtpForVerification() {
      this.configureRecaptcha();
      const phoneNumber = "+91" + this.userMobile; //user phone number
      const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
      firebase.auth().languageCode = "en";

      firebase.auth()
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
          // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
          // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
          this.$toast.success("Otp sent successfully");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Error; SMS not sent
          console.log("Error", error);
        });
    },
    
    
}
</script>
```

please make sure you have installed firebase and @nuxtjs/firebase

hope this will help somebody :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `sign-in-button` do  "Protected by reCAPTCHA"